# How to convert a file with data in key = value format to a csv file in unix shell scripting?

Tags: shell, unix, csv

I have an input file of the format:

```
(key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3)
(key1=value4,key2=value5,key3=value6)
```

I want to convert this file to a csv file like:

```
key1,key2,key3
value1,value2,value3
value4,value5,value6
```

How can i do this in a shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `awk` to process this file:

```
awk -F'[=(),]' -v OFS=, 'NR==1{for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF-2)?OFS:ORS}
              {for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF-2)?OFS:ORS}' input
key1,key2,key3
value1,value2,value3
value4,value5,value6
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F'[=(),]'` - Make field separator as one of those characters in character class: `[=(),]`
- `-v OFS=,` - Make output field separator as comma
- `NR==1` - Execute this block for first record only
- `'NR==1{...}` Will print all the headers of input file by printing fields 2, 4, 6...
- `{for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=2) ...}` Will print all cells by printing fields 3, 5, 7...